# jQuery undefined когда пытаюсь получить val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, alert

Есть input :

```
<input type="hidden" value="300" name="from10to30"/>
```

Есть кнопка :

```
<input type="button" id="b" value="Расчитать"/>
```

Мой jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#b").click(function(){
    var a = $('#from30toMore').val();
    alert(a);
});   });
```

И при нажатии на кнопку появляется alert с содержанием 'undefined'.
Уже почти 2 дня ищу ответ на свой вопрос, и все без толку..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#from30toMore')` - селектор по `id`. Добавьте `id`:

```
<input type="hidden" value="300" name="from10to30" id="from10toMore"/>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, до этого момента думал, что к элементам по 'name' надо обращаться)